# Advice when using COM Object/CComPtr and the STL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, stl, atl

I am doing some COM related things with directshow such as:

```
typedef CComPtr<IBaseFilter> AutoIBaseFilterPtr;
map<CString, AutoIBaseFilterPtr> _filterMap;
```

To store a list of directShow related com objects and their friendly name.

After finding [this article (See:Problem 2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/05/25/stl-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-2010-beta-1.aspx) on how changes in VC10 compiler might effect previously OK code, I am wondering if there are any more things to watch out for when mixing the STL and CComPtr or prehaps just mixing the STL and COM in general.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the link to that article.

Comment: I thought `CAdapt` was recommended or even necessary for STL<->ATL bridging for quite some time?

Comment: I am still a bit new to COM so I wasn't really aware of CAdapt's use with the STL but looking at it, yes, it seems like it is recommended but I am guessing there are quite a few people out there that might have a nasty surprise when attempting to compile their program under VC10. My question is sort of aimed at finding out more cases where I might fall into a nasty trap. Thanks for the tag edits too btw.

Comment: I've had the fun of tracking down and fixing bugs only to find they were caused by a lack of CAdapt use - joy to a complier that stops you at build time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only slight thing I can think of that hasn't been mentioned is that `CAdapt` is required for `CComBSTR` as well as `CComPtr`, because it overloads `operator&` too.

In fact, it is overloading `operator&` that makes `CAdapt` necessary, as many STL containers require that taking the address of something X returns a pointer to said X.

Comment: Marked as answer, even though my question was sort of open ended, you are the only one to reply :)

Comment: `CAdapt` is no longer required for either `CComPtr` nor `CComBSTR` for all STL containers and most STL algorithms in VC2010 RTM. This is because it now uses `std::addressof` (a new thing in C++0x) rather than applying `operator&` directly to obtain address of object, and that helper function works around any overloaded `operator&`, and always provides the actual pointer.

Comment: Pavel; thanks for the added info, I still haven't looked into VS2010. I need to read up on std::addressof -- looks interesting!